# Identity Server 4 AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache Configure TimeToLive

Tags: identityserver4

I am using the extension:

`services.AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache();`

in Asp.Net Core,  to store the state in the distributed cache which is implemented using Redis:

```
services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options => {
                options.Configuration = Configuration[RedisConnection];
            });
```

but it seems that the entries in the Redis cache are not set with TTL:
[image]

Is there a setting to control the TTL of the keys that get created in the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already [reported](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/3270). Waiting for response. (Please, mention that you need this, there too!)

For the moment we use an ugly inheritor. Ugly because the base has no virtual methods and in addition requires a helper `internal class ConfigureOpenIdConnectOptionsTTL : IPostConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>` (mostly copy&paste again) but at least it fixed "slow redis in production".

```cs
public class DistributedCacheStateDataFormatterTTL: 
    DistributedCacheStateDataFormatter, ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationProperties>
{
    public static readonly TimeSpan DefaultCacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;
    private readonly string _name;

    public DistributedCacheStateDataFormatterTTL(
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContext, string name) : base(httpContext, name)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
        _name = name;
    }
    private string CacheKeyPrefix => "DistributedCacheStateDataFormatter";

    private IDistributedCache Cache =>
        _httpContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IDistributedCache>();
    private IDataProtector Protector =>
       _httpContext.HttpContext.RequestServices
       .GetRequiredService<IDataProtectionProvider>()
       .CreateProtector(CacheKeyPrefix, _name);

    string ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationProperties>
        .Protect(AuthenticationProperties data)
    {
         return ((ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationProperties>)this).
             Protect(data, string.Empty);
    }


    string ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationProperties>
        .Protect(AuthenticationProperties data, string purpose)
    {
         var key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
         var cacheKey = $"{CacheKeyPrefix}-{purpose}-{key}";
         var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, new JsonSerializerSettings()
         {
             DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
             NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
         });

         var options = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions();
         if (data.ExpiresUtc.HasValue)
             options.SetAbsoluteExpiration(data.ExpiresUtc.Value);
         else
             options.SetSlidingExpiration(DefaultCacheDuration);

         // Rather than encrypt the full AuthenticationProperties
         // cache the data and encrypt the key that points to the data
         Cache.SetString(cacheKey, json, options);

         return Protector.Protect(key);
    }
}
```

```cs
internal class ConfigureOpenIdConnectOptionsTTL : IPostConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>
{
    private string[] _schemes;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public ConfigureOpenIdConnectOptionsTTL(string[] schemes, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _schemes = schemes ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(schemes));
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
    }

    public void PostConfigure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
    {
        // no schemes means configure them all
        if (_schemes.Length == 0 || _schemes.Contains(name))
        {
            options.StateDataFormat = new DistributedCacheStateDataFormatterTTL(_httpContextAccessor, name);
        }
    }


    public static IServiceCollection AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache(
        IServiceCollection services,
        params string[] schemes)
    {
        services.RemoveAll<IPostConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>>();
        services.AddSingleton<IPostConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>>(
            svcs => new ConfigureOpenIdConnectOptionsTTL(
                    schemes,
                    svcs.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>())
            );

        return services;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for opening the issue and the PR. Also, you mentioned that it also fixed "slow redis in production", were you experiencing timeouts? I ended up finding this problem because I was looking for the reason my redis cache was throwing timeout exceptions.

Comment: I was exactly *looking for the reason my redis cache was throwing timeout exceptions*, and found there a million similar records...